# Shiny tabsetPanel take full width

Tags: r, shiny

Is it possible to have a tabset panel in Shiny, where the tabPanels use the full width? Is it possible to add the `nav-fill` class to the tabsetPanel? Or is it not possible, because Shiny is build with Bootstrap 3?

The result should look like https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#fill-and-justify

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tabsetPanel(
    # class = "navlist-fill",
    tabPanel("Tab 1"),
    tabPanel("Tab 2"),
    tabPanel("Tab 3")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The link you posted makes sense and is probably a better way of doing it. We could make a custom widget to perform this. For now, here is a workaround using some simple css.

The CSS Selector here is very general, you should probably be more specific but here is an idea.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  tags$head(
    tags$style(HTML("
      .nav li {
        width: 32vw;
      }
    "))),
  tabsetPanel(id = "tab_panel",
    tabPanel("Tab 1"),
    tabPanel("Tab 2"),
    tabPanel("Tab 3")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```